# concat string with 0 does not work in vbScript

Tags: vbscript, concatenation

I tried each of the following code in VbScript but it does not give desired output:

```
alert("Day=" + <%= (CStr("0") + "6")%>);
alert("Day=" + <%= (0 + "6")%>);
alert("Day=" + <%= ("0" + "6")%>);
alert("Day=" + <%= (CStr(0) + "6")%>);
```

I also used **&** instead of **+**

```
alert("Day=" + <%= (CStr("0") & "6")%>);
alert("Day=" + <%= (0 & "6")%>);
alert("Day=" + <%= ("0" & "6")%>);
alert("Day=" + <%= (CStr(0) & "6")%>);
```

All of the above give the same output: **Day=6**

If I use 1 instead of 0 it works (eg. it gives output: **Day=16**)

But I want this output:**Day=06**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this client-javascript with serverside asp-vbscript code ?

Compose your string in servercode first, then show it
Put this in a asp file and it give Day=06 in your browser

```
<%str = "'Day=" & "0" & "6'" '=> Day=06%>
<script>
document.write(<%=str%>) 
</script>
```